# Is it possible to return xml from javascript function to the object in odoo?

Tags: javascript, odoo, odoo-8

Am trying to pass some values from a javascript function to a model .
Is it possible to add to the context using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jsonrpc you can provide a custom context when calling methods from your model.

```
var uid = YOURUSERID;
var context = {};

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'http://localhost:8069/web/dataset/call_kw',
        dataType: 'json',
        async: true,
        data: JSON.stringify({
                              'jsonrpc':'2.0',
                              'method':'call',
                              'params':{
                                        'model':'your.model',
                                        'args':[],
                                        'context':context,
                                        'kwargs':{},
                                        'method':'YOURMETHOD'
                              },
                              id': uid
        }),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function ( data ) {
                                    console.log( data );
        },
        failure: function( data ){
                                  console.log( JSON.stringify( data ) );
        }
})
```